# Vim shell bindings (set -o vi) on iTerm2

Tags: bash, vi, osx-lion

Trouble with history when using bash vi bindings on iTerm2 on Lion. (I had the same problem with iTerm when I switched to Lion.)

Hard to explain exactly, but when I hit k to go to most recent command, it pushes the cursor forward a few characters, so it's no longer at start of line. And if I then hit k again, it doesn't clear the characters before the cursor.

Comment: What's in your `~/.inputrc`?

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with iTerm, but this sounds like a termcap problem, where bash (or really, readline/ncurses underneath it) thinks that the terminal needs different characters for cursor movement than it really does.  Fix is to make sure TERM is correct and/or that your termcap/terminfo definitions are up to date.

Comment: @evil Actually that fixed it. I have "xterm" set by default, tried several TERM settings, but then I "unset TERM" and that worked!